# Why Name error is showing in logging.info?

Tags: python, function, logging

I am getting error for the below code:

> logging.info("Hypotenuse of {a}, {b} is {c}".format(a=3, b=4, c=hypotenuse(a,b)))
>   NameError: name 'a' is not defined

---

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def hypotenuse(a, b):
    """Compute the hypotenuse"""
    return (a**2 + b**2)**0.5

logging.info("Hypotenuse of {a}, {b} is {c}".format(a=3, b=4, c=hypotenuse(a,b)))
```

Desired Out

```
INFO:root:Hypotenuse of 3, 4 is 5.0
```

Comment: why c=hypotenuse(a,b) not working

Comment: you need to specify the value

Comment: `a=3` does not assign to a variable that the call to `hypotenuse` has access to; it only sets the value of a keyword argument for the call to `format`.

Comment: Your attempt is basically the same as `"Hypotenuse of {x}, {y} is {c}".format(x=3, y=4, c=hypotenuse(a, b))`.

Comment: `logging.info` can format the string for you: `logging.info("Hypotenuse of %f, %f is %f", a, b, hypotenuse(a, b))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logging.info("Hypotenuse of {a}, {b} is {c}".format(a=3,b=4, c=hypotenuse(3,4)))
```

Comment: c=hypotenuse(a,b)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the only way it will work is defining the variables before the call:

```
a,b = (3,4)
logging.info("Hypotenuse of {a}, {b} is {c}".format(a=a, b=b, c=hypotenuse(a,b))
```

possibly a little clearer:

```
a,b = (3,4)
logging.info("Hypotenuse of {}, {} is {}".format(a, b, hypotenuse(a,b))
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the pre-defined `a` and `b` are necessary if you want to use the same values for `format`'s keyword arguments and the call to `hypotenuse`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, otherwise `a` and `b` only exist for `format`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
a = 3
b = 4
logging.info(f'Hypotenuse of {a}, {b} is {hypotenuse(a, b)}')
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are likely already set, but if `c` isn't, you can embed the call to `hypotenuse` directly in the format string: `"Hypotenuse of {a}, {b} is {hypotenuse(a, b)}"`.